# How to make a footer a textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, footer

My Code:

```
<div style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:70px; background-color:yellow; padding:5px; bottom:0px; ">
        test content :D
    </div>
```

I want a text area to be a footer like there is in a messenger(chat).[Here is how my footer text-area should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrCql.jpg)

[Inshort]
I have a div which is a footer but i want a text-area to be a footer

And when i changed the div to text-area i am not able to center it.
[Like in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG53H.png)

Comment: and... what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dekel I have tried adding a id to the div ,same as the text-area ,but it obviously did not work

Comment: did you try to change the `<div>` tag to `<textarea>` tag? this is what you are looking for...

Comment: @Dekel It worked! ..thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :) Care if I add this as and answer and you accept it?

Comment: Sure .. :).....

Comment: @Dekel if you dont mind me asking,can you recheck the edited question?..I cannot center it

Comment: If the width of the textarea is 100% - how exactly would you like to center it?

Comment: @Dekel I have changed 100% to 20% you can check the image link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change your `<div...>` element to `<textarea...>` element.

```
<textarea style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:70px; background-color:yellow; padding:5px; bottom:0px; ">
    test content :D
</textarea>
```

Comment: Could you check the edited question..appreciate it if you could

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `<div>` as the container for a `<form>` element which contains all your form elements and in this case a text area.

Comment: Thanks ,Could you please guide me on how to do that